# how to know compaign source when boadcasting intent from adb to test google analytics

Tags: android, android-intent, google-analytics

When broadcasting -

adb shell am broadcast -a com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER -n com.train.omitraapp/com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver --es referrer "&utm_source=omitra&utm_medium=byphone&utm_campaign=Set%20Pickup%20Reminder"

getting this response

Broadcasting: Intent { act=com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER cmp=com.train.omitraapp/com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver (has extras) }

Broadcast completed: result=0

but when again run application and see log cat then it shows
Thread[GAThread,5,main]: No campaign data found.